# What is the difference null and undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I can not understand what is the main difference between null and undefined.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: `console.log(a)` : `a` is undefined. It doesn't exist at all. `typeof a === "undefined"`. But if you do `const a = null`, then `a` is defined. Its value is a null object, but it is defined and exists. `typeof a === "object"`.

Answer (score 1):

**Null**: It is the intentional absence of the value. It is one of the primitive values of JavaScript.

**Undefined**: It means the value does not exist in the compiler. It is a global object.